# C# application crashes in Windows CE

Tags: c#, crash, windows-ce

I have some console C# application, which is working on Windows CE environment. This application start the other main application.This part is working. But also it have to detect when/if main application crash and in this case restart main application. Is there any way to detect application crash by program?

Thanks, Slava.

Comment: Isn't it better to find the cause of crash, instead of detecting it.

Comment: No.This is what I required to do.If it crashes-restart. Main app - is not my application,and I do not know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, which is pretty match to my needs.I just put the application to \Windows\StartUp folder and that is it. After restart all applications in StartUp folder are coming up,including MyApp.